# XDMF - Extract component from vector field using Hyperslab

Tags: xml, paraview

I am trying to load a single component of a vector field stored in the file `uvw_000001.bin`.

I am using the XDMF file below which loads the field values into the variable `q` just fine, i.e. I can view its components in Paraview.

The second variable `u` where I try  to extract the first component of the vector field is not available in Paraview.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE Xdmf SYSTEM "Xdmf.dtd" []>

<Xdmf Version="3.0">

  <Domain>

    <Grid Name="staggered_east" GridType="Uniform">

      <Topology TopologyType="3DRectMesh" NumberOfElements="34 34 34"/>

      <Geometry GeometryType="VXVYVZ">
        <DataItem Dimensions="34" NumberType="Float" Precision="4" Format="XML">   
          0.0000000000000000 0.10000000000000001 0.20000000000000001 0.30000000000000004 0.40000000000000002 0.50000000000000000 0.60000000000000020 0.70000000000000007 0.80000000000000004 0.90000000000000002 1.0000000000000000 1.1000000000000001 1.2000000000000002 1.3000000000000000 1.4000000000000001 1.5000000000000000 1.6000000000000001 1.7000000000000002 1.8000000000000000 1.9000000000000001 2.0000000000000000 2.1000000000000001 2.2000000000000002 2.3000000000000003 2.4000000000000004       2.5000000000000000 2.6000000000000001 2.7000000000000002 2.8000000000000003 2.9000000000000004 3.0000000000000000 3.1000000000000001 3.2000000000000002 3.3000000000000003
        </DataItem>
        <DataItem Dimensions="34" NumberType="Float" Precision="4" Format="XML">   
          -5.0000000000000003E-002 5.0000000000000003E-002 0.15000000000000002 0.25000000000000000 0.35000000000000003 0.45000000000000001 0.55000000000000004 0.65000000000000013 0.75000000000000000 0.85000000000000009 0.94999999999999996 1.0500000000000000 1.1500000000000001 1.2500000000000000 1.3500000000000001 1.4500000000000002 1.5500000000000000 1.6500000000000001 1.7500000000000000 1.8500000000000001 1.9500000000000002 2.0499999999999998 2.1500000000000004 2.2500000000000000 2.3500000000000005      2.4500000000000002 2.5499999999999998 2.6500000000000004 2.7500000000000000 2.8500000000000005 2.9500000000000002 3.0499999999999998 3.1500000000000004 3.2500000000000000 
        </DataItem>
        <DataItem Dimensions="34" NumberType="Float" Precision="4" Format="XML">   
          -5.0000000000000003E-002 5.0000000000000003E-002 0.15000000000000002 0.25000000000000000 0.35000000000000003 0.45000000000000001 0.55000000000000004 0.65000000000000013 0.75000000000000000 0.85000000000000009 0.94999999999999996 1.0500000000000000 1.1500000000000001 1.2500000000000000 1.3500000000000001 1.4500000000000002 1.5500000000000000 1.6500000000000001 1.7500000000000000 1.8500000000000001 1.9500000000000002 2.0499999999999998 2.1500000000000004 2.2500000000000000 2.3500000000000005      2.4500000000000002 2.5499999999999998 2.6500000000000004 2.7500000000000000 2.8500000000000005 2.9500000000000002 3.0499999999999998 3.1500000000000004 3.2500000000000000 
        </DataItem>
      </Geometry>


      <Attribute Name="q" AttributeType="Scalar" Center="Node">

        <DataItem 
          ItemType="Uniform"
          Name="uvw_s"
          Format="Binary"
          Dimensions="34 34 34 3"
          DataType="Float" Precision="8" Endian="Big" Seek="8"
          >
          uvw_000001.bin
        </DataItem>

      </Attribute>


      <Attribute Name="u" AttributeType="Scalar" Center="Node">

        <DataItem 
          ItemType="HyperSlab"
          Dimensions="34 34 34"
          Type="HyperSlab">

          <DataItem
            Dimensions="3 4"
            Format="XML">
            0   0  0  0
            1   1  1  1
            34 34 34  1
          </DataItem>

          <DataItem 
            ItemType="Uniform"
            Name="uvw"
            Format="Binary"
            Dimensions="34 34 34 3"
            DataType="Float" Precision="8" Endian="Big" Seek="8"
            >
            uvw_000001.bin
          </DataItem>

        </DataItem>

      </Attribute>


    </Grid>

  </Domain>

</Xdmf>
```

**Update**
I now realized that the code actually works when using Paraview's xdmf reader instead of xdmf3. The latter is the default.

**Is there any way of achieving the same result with the xdmf3 reader?**

Comment: Once again, what you are trying to do either is not supported by the Xdmf format, or is not implemented in the vtkXmfReader. You may want to tag this question with Xdmf.

Comment: @MathieuWestphal I'd love to tag it but I don't have the right to.

Comment: Indeed, the tag does not exist. Lets hope that someone knowing the format shime in here.